# Finding the $n^{th}$ derivative of $\frac{x^n}{(1+x)}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, closed-form

Find the $n^{th}$ derivative of $\frac{x^n}{(1+x)}$ .
I think we have to use Leibnitz's Formula to evaluate this, but I haven't succeeded in it as well. I have already received an answer of $\frac {x^n}{(1+x)}$, that was a bit simpler maybe, but I could not get this one...hope some one can help.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Have you considered using the chain rule with the function $x\mapsto -x$?

Comment: put $f(x)=x^n/(1+x)$ and $g(x)=x^n/(1-x)$. Compare $f(x)$ and $g(-x)$.

Answer (score 15):

One may recall that
$$
1-x+x^2-x^3+\dots+(-1)^{n-1}x^{n-1}=\frac1{x+1}-(-1)^n\frac{x^n}{x+1},\qquad x \neq-1,
$$ then differentiating $n$ times gives easily
$$
0=\left(\frac1{x+1} \right)^{(n)}-(-1)^n\left(\frac{x^n}{x+1}\right)^{(n)}
$$ or

> $$
> \left(\frac{x^n}{x+1}\right)^{(n)}=(-1)^n\left(\frac1{x+1} \right)^{(n)}=\color{blue}{\frac{n!}{(x+1)^{n+1}}},\quad \quad x \neq-1.
> $$

Comment: Can you tell me that is $(x+1)\cdot (1-x+x^2-x^3+\cdot\cdot\cdot+x^{n-1})=1+x^n$ true? I according this method to do and find it wrong, but I can tell the reason.

Comment: @Rowan Typo edited! Thank you very much!

Comment: uhh, actually I wonder how you get "one may recall that" part. Can you explain it.

Comment: @Rowan The following identity is standard: $(1-x)(1+x+\ldots+x^{n-1})=1-x^n$, then just put $x \to -x$ to get the first identity in the answer above. Hoping to be clear.

Comment: Abundantly clear! Thanks